# Parse PFFile progressBlock:^(int percentDone) { } is not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pffile, back4app

I am saving a `PFFile` on `Back4App` server with Parse SDK, here is the code snippet

```
PFFile *videoFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"video.mp4" data:data];
[videoFile saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    if (succeeded) {
        handler(obj,nil);

    } else {
        handler(nil,error);

    }

} progressBlock:^(int percentDone) {
    progress(percentDone);

}];
```

But in the above code, I am not getting progress in the `progressBlock`. I have put a breakpoint there but this block is not getting executed.

Also, I have checked the object of `PFFile` and the object is valid.

Parse SDK Version - **1.14.2**

Xcode Version - **8.0**

Comment: and success block is called?

Comment: @NeilGaliaskarov Yes Success block is getting called

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the guide: http://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#the-pffile

Also, can you please confirm if the size from the file is less than 20MB?

If you prefer, you can open the Logs at Server side, to find a message error or check if the POST method is called or it is not being executed.